# Comparing two list of lists and getting partial/full matches in python

Tags: python, regex, list, pattern-matching, text-extraction

I have a csv and a text file. The csv has 3 columns. Sample csv data:

```
Pack Type   Component Type        Component Material
Blister       Foil                    Aluminium
Blister      Base Web                 PVC/PVDC
Bottle     Cylindrically Bottles    
Bottle       Screw Type Cap         Polypropylene
```

---

Sample text data:

```
The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured
polyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of
tablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured
polypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring.
```

I have two list of lists. list 1 comes from the csv and list 2 comes from the text file.

```
list 1 = [['Bottle', 'Screw Type Cap', 'Polypropylene'], ['Bottle', 'Safety Ring', ''], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC'], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVD/PVDC'], ['Bottle', 'Square Shaped Bottle', 'Polyethylene'], ['Bottle', 'Child Resistant (CR) Cap', 'Polypropylene']]

list 2 = [['The', 'tablets', 'are', 'filled', 'into', 'cylindrically', 'shaped', 'bottles', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured', 'polyethylene.', 'The', 'volumes', 'of', 'the', 'bottles', 'depend', 'on', 'the', 'tablet', 'strength', 'and', 'amount', 'of', 'tablets,', 'ranging', 'from', '20', 'to', '175', 'ml.', 'The', 'screw', 'type', 'cap', 'is', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured', 'polypropylene', 'and', 'is', 'equipped', 'with', 'a', 'tamper', 'proof', 'ring.'], ['PVC/PVDC', 'blister', 'pack'], ['Blisters', 'are', 'made', 'in', 'a', 'thermo-forming', 'process', 'from', 'a', 'PVC/PVDC', 'base', 'web.', 'Each', 'tablet', 'is', 'filled', 'into', 'a', 'separate', 'blister', 'and', 'a', 'lidding', 'foil', 'of', 'aluminium', 'is', 'welded', 'on.', 'The', 'blisters', 'are', 'opened', 'by', 'pressing', 'the', 'tablets', 'through', 'the', 'lidding', 'foil.', 'PVDC', 'foil', 'is', 'in', 'contact', 'with', 'the', 'tablets.']]
```

I want to search for each list1 string inside each list of list 2. So, I am trying to match the tokens of list 1 to list2. If all the tokens of one list of list 1 is found inside a list of list 2, a match should be returned and I want to identify that list in list 2 which had all the tokens of a particular list of list 1 and return the entire matched list 2 list, with the matched list of list 1.

```
Output expected:

paragraph: ['Blisters', 'are', 'made', 'in', 'a', 'thermo-forming', 'process', 'from', 'a', 'PVC/PVDC', 'base', 'web.', 'Each', 'tablet', 'is', 'filled', 'into', 'a', 'separate', 'blister', 'and', 'a', 'lidding', 'foil', 'of', 'aluminium', 'is', 'welded', 'on.', 'The', 'blisters', 'are', 'opened', 'by', 'pressing', 'the', 'tablets', 'through', 'the', 'lidding', 'foil.', 'PVDC', 'foil', 'is', 'in', 'contact', 'with', 'the', 'tablets.'], Pack Type: Blister, Component Type: 'Base Web', Component Material:  'PVD/PVDC'
```

Questions:

```
Q1. How do I make 'Base Web' match with 'base', 'web.' in list 2
Q2. **** In the CSV, the 3rd row has no data in the 3rd column. If such a case is encountered, I want to ignore the empty 3rd column and match the remaining value from 2 columns.
Q3. I want partial matches to be extracted likewise
```

Code till now:

```
import re,csv
filepath = r'C:\Users\0903882.txt'

with open(filepath) as f:
    data=f.read()
    paragraphs=data.split("\n\n")
    #print(paragraphs)

all_words=[]
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    words=paragraph.split()
    all_words.append(words)

print(all_words)


inputfile = r"C:\Users\metadata.csv"                
inputm = []

with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        #types = row.split(',')
        inputm.append(row)

final_ref = [] 
for lists in inputm:
    final_ref.append(str(lists[0]).split(','))

print(final_ref)
```

which gives me 2 list of lists to compare

Comment: fyi you cant name a list with a space in it... and list1 contains 'Base Web' while list2 contains 'base', 'web.' so some further splitting needs to occur when making the lists if your going to just loop through and compare list1 to list2 as you describe

Comment: if you make it to the point where things are split correctly, I suggest comparing lowercase using set(list1[i]).issubset(list2[j])